# Visual Studio equivalent of Eclipse syso

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio, code-snippets

Yesterday a friend showed me a nice way to type `System.out.println("")`,

That is `syso` + `ctrl`-`space` and it is auto-generated.

Is there a way to do something like it with `c#` -  `Console.WriteLine("")` ?

Comment: Try snippets `crtl+k+s`, if there is no Console.Writeline snippet make your own

Comment: @wudzik, cw doesn't show up in `ctrl+k+s` but it does exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a default, `Console.WriteLine()` has `cw` code snippet. Just write `cw` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

You can create your own code snippets also.

Take a look;

- [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Creating a Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Code Snippet in Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96088/Code-Snippet-in-Visual-Studio)

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in snippet `cw`.

Comment: To invoke: Type `cw` and hit the Tab key.